# Knex migrate:latest doesn't create tables from docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, knex.js

I'm working on an app, and I need to pre-populate **knex** database schema on **docker** container startup (*only if database is empty*).

If I will execute it manually: `yarn knex --knexfile config/knexfile.js migrate:latest` inside a container - it works, but I need to do that on a docker container startup.

**Dockerfile.dev**

```
FROM node:18.15.0-alpine3.17

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package*.json yarn*.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

**docker-compose-dev.yml**

```
backend:
    container_name: backend-dev
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./backend/.env.dev
    command: bash -c "yarn knex --knexfile ./config/knexfile.js migrate:latest" && "node server.js"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - network
    depends_on: 
      - db
```

No errors or exceptions, but inside DB container there are no relations created from a migration.

I'm open for ideas.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now nothing is happening because you're using `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile and separately setting a `command:` in your Compose setup.  When you have both entrypoint and a command settings, the command is passed as additional arguments to the entrypoint, and so you'll see `bash`, `-c`, and three more arguments as arguments to your Node application.

The first thing I'd change here is to change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in the Dockerfile.  This will let the Compose `command:` override take effect.  There is a syntax problem in it (the two commands need to be in the same quoted string; `sh -c` only takes one argument) but if you fix that then migrations should work.

But I'd actually implement this as an *entrypoint wrapper script*.  If the `CMD` is the actual command to run, and it gets passed as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`, then you can use `ENTRYPOINT` for a script that does first-time setup and then runs the command that's passed to it as arguments.  For example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Run migrations
yarn knex --knexfile ./config/knexfile.js migrate:latest

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Make sure this file is checked in to source control as executable, and if you're on a Windows system, that it has Unix (LF-only) line endings.  Your existing `COPY` command will copy it into the image, so all you need to do is run it

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["node", "server.js"]       # what you currently have as ENTRYPOINT
```

and you do not need to override the `command:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

In the question you add a proviso "only if the database is empty".  The setup I've shown here will run the database migrations unconditionally.  However, the entrypoint script is just a shell script, and you can write whatever logic you need to in there.  Also since it's just a shell script, you can run it locally if you need to `./entrypoint.sh echo hello` in the course of developing and debugging it.

Comment: For other people, don't forget to execute RUN [ "chmod", "+x", "./path/to/script" ]

Comment: "Make sure this file is checked in to source control as executable."  `COPY` will preserve the executable bit from the permissions.